# Cómo borro un login banner?

Tags: kali-linux

instale un login banner de Ivam3 y después instale sys0-termux que trae un login banner y quiero eliminar el de Ivam3 porque cada vez que entro a termux tengo que loggearme 2 veces alguien que me ayude gracias

Comment: ¿Tienes algún código al respecto?

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que instalaste fue [esto](https://github.com/ivam3/Termux_login) básicamente puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
nano /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/etc/bash.bashrc
```

Y buscar las línea que dice:

```
source /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/var/log/login-termux
```

Y eliminarla, ya con eso no te sale de nuevo el login de Ivam3